# Autocomplete strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I have autocomplete with DataTemplate as:

```
<my:AutoCompleteBox FontSize="18" TextChanged="z_TextChanged" SelectionChanged="z_SelectionChanged" Width="220" Name="z" FilterMode="Contains" >
                    <my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                </my:AutoCompleteBox>
```

And binding items like:

```
myList = ListsClass.pList.Where(y => y.wID == wID).Distinct().ToList();
z.ItemsSource = myList;
```

myList type: SearchProd, with string name, int ID etc.

My problem is that, when I put one letter on autocomplete I can see all items which name contains entered letter. But when i click down/up arrow i can see on AutoComplete.Text: myNameSpace.Classes.SearchProd.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to bind to the Text property...

Comment: Yes, as TextBlock Text I'd like to have name from searchProd class. So actually dont understand Your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z.ValueMemberPath = "name"; was missing in code behind.